# Undefined Method errors in rake tasks and model methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to return a sum using `number_to_currency`, but whenever I try to use this method inside a rake task or model class instance, I get `NoMethodError: undefined method 'number_to_currency' for main:Object`

Happens in console too. Any suggestions on why I can't use basic methods inside rake tasks or models?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`number_to_currency`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_to_currency) is a view helper so it is generally only available within views. You could do this:

```
include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper
```

inside a class if you need to use it somewhere else. Think twice about your design though, using a view helper while messing around in the console is fine but you usually want to push your formatting out to the edges (i.e. views).

Answer (score 1):

Here’s how it works:

Make a folder RAILS ROOT/lib/core_extensions
In there, create a file named fixenum_extensions.rb
Copy/paste the code below into that file.
In your environment.rb file, put this line:

```
RAILS_ROOT = "#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/.." unless defined?(RAILS_ROOT)
```

And this line:

```
require "#{RAILS_ROOT}/lib/core_extensions/fixnum_extensions"
```

And restart your application

```
###

require 'rubygems'
require 'action_view'

class Fixnum
  def to_currency(options = {})
    ActionView::Base.new.number_to_currency(self, options)
  end
end

###
```